# UITableView indexPath is messing up my Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

So I just got this error after trying to access the **SECOND** item in my array. When I access the first item in my array in my table view cell nothing is wrong. But when I access the 2 cell / item in my array I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** **-[**__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

My breakpoints tell my my code is breaking at my prepareForSegue method. Can anyone please help me figure out what's wrong with my code?:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Push"]) {

        HistoryDetailsViewController *detailVC=(HistoryDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];



        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
NSManagedObject *YouOweData = [YouOweArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];                
[detailVC setCellNumString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [YouOweData valueForKey:@"youOweCellNum"]]];
            [detailVC setDateString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cell.detailTextLabel.text]];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {

        NSManagedObject *TheyOweData = [SomeonesOwesYouArray     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];                
[detailVC setCellNumString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [TheyOweData   valueForKey:@"theyOweCellNum"]]];
            [detailVC setDateString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cell.detailTextLabel.text]];
        }
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Log the contents of the arrays - is it what you expected? Which array is driving the table? Why are you accessing both arrays before you check the section (this is probably the issue).

Comment: k, ill log the contents and and access them when they should be accessed

Comment: when i log the arrays when I have 1 object in the YouOweArray I get this: This is in the you owe array (null)
2014-02-07 11:24:33.021 iOU[1054:70b] This is in the someone owes you array (null)

Comment: Ok I also changed it so I access the arrays individually in the if / else statement

Comment: That error is saying that you have one object in your array and you are trying to access item number 2.  I'm confused on how you are confused.  If you want to access more than one object from an array moke sure there is more than one object in it.

Comment: The thing is in my table view when I add one object via the settings screen, I only populate one object. I can't access that object for some reason now because apparently nothing is in it. I've been pulling my hair for a week trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I fixed the problem. The reason my array was null was because it was grabbing objects that weren't even there. My viewDidAppear method BELOW it was grabbing the contents, so I cut and pasted it ABOVE the prepareForSegue